# MySQL - Delete first character but only if it is a specified value

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `Table1` that looks like this

```
ID  VALUES
1   050
2   50
3   100
4   010
5   300
```

I need to update the targeted value through the `ID`. In this case I want to remove leading `0` where `ID` is `1`. This is the end result below:

```
ID  VALUES
1   50
2   50
3   100
4   010
5   300
```

Bear in mind that `Id 4` is remained the same. As I have only specified `Id 1` to remove that zero.

Reason I want to do this way, is because I wan't to learn how to remove the leading zero and at the same time how I can remove the leading zero for a specific `ID`.

Comment: Do you want to display the rows OR want to update them without at the beginning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to update the values in your table:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET `values` = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM `values`)
WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
id  values
1   50
2   50
3   100
4   010
5   300
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=161bf20b70d05ea04628696a3d4d1813)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
update tablename set value=substr(value,2,length(value)-1)
  where id=1
```

Comment: what if I wanted to only change a few records? and keep all the other 0's?

Comment: @Eduard, I've updated it - you can check - though I am not sure whether it'll serve your purpose or not

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT `id`,
(CASE
  WHEN (LEFT(`values`,1) = 0 AND `id` = 1) THEN SUBSTR(`values`,2)
  ELSE
 `values`
  END
) `values`
FROM `data`
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb8139/5)